# POST request with HttpURLConnetion and read response from server - Android

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am a novice to Android. I have gone through many similar questions in StackOverflow too, but unable to get a gist.

I am sending a post request to a server with username and password. My server just checks if the credentials are true, and sends "success" or "Fail" response. I just have to catch the response form the server --that's all. Below is what I have come across so far.

```
public String CheckUserAuthentication(String name, String pass) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://sample.com?username=" + name + "&password=" + pass);
        try {

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    }
    return Response;
}
```

I would be glad if anyone would suggest me my next step to forward the request and receive the response back from server.

Comment: username & password in the Url, looks like for GET request, not POST, pls search more sample code available in SO :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    String jsonParamsString = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
    outputStream.writeBytes("request=" + jsonParamsString);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    // get response
    InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
    responseStreamReader.close();

    String response = stringBuilder.toString();
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

The result is in response which is then converted to a json object, you can then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a link with an example of what you need.It is not 100% for android,but the code should work on the android platform (is Java,duh).

Just copy,paste it and do the necesary modifications.

Cheers,
Bob

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your link. The code looks simple and understandable. But i got a problem. As soon as i introduce DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());, my application fails. I have not been able to understand the problem. There is no uncaught exception too. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Use **AsyncTask** Like This

```
new MyTaskLogin().execute(Constant.LOGIN_URL + "&email=" + strUserEmail
                    + "&password=" + strUserPassword );
```

**AsynchTask Code :-**

```
private class MyTaskLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return JsonUtils.getJSONString(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
            setSweetDialog(SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE,
                    getString(R.string.conn_msg1),
                    getString(R.string.nodata));

        } else {

            try {
                JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson
                        .getJSONArray(Constant.USER_LOGIN_ARRAY);
                JSONObject objJson = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (objJson.has(Constant.USER_LOGIN_MSG)) {
                        strMessage = objJson
                                .getString(Constant.USER_LOGIN_MSG);
                        Constant.GET_SUCCESS_MSG = objJson
                                .getInt(Constant.USER_LOGIN_SUCESS);
                    } else {
                        Constant.GET_SUCCESS_MSG = objJson
                                .getInt(Constant.USER_LOGIN_SUCESS);
                        strUserEmail = objJson
                                .getString("string_name1");
                        strUserName = objJson
                                .getString("string_name2");

                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            setResult();
        }

    }
}
```